# Wiremock not matching encoded url

Tags: java, spring, wiremock

I can't get wiremock to match encoded URL's

```
String encodedURL="/a?b%3D5";

String url = URLDecoder.decode(encodedURL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
System.out.println("Decoded = " + url);
WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo(encodedURL))
        .willReturn(jsonResponse(200, "abc")));

// Info such as port numbers is also available
int port = wmRuntimeInfo.getHttpPort();
RestTemplate r = new RestTemplate();
    
String result  = r.getForObject("http://localhost:" +port+encodedURL,String.class);
System.out.println("Result = " + result);
```

and wiremock reports

> closest stub = /a?b%3D5   request = /a?b%253D5

If I call with the decoded url , wiremock reports

> closest stub = /a?b=5   request = /a?b%253D5

I'm using wiremock 2.32.0, junit 5, spring boot 2.6.3
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You pass the encoded path and query (encodedUrl) to the RestTemplate's GET request. However, RestTemplate will encode the url for you. this means that the already encoded path and query are encoded again. Try using: `r.getForObject("http://localhost:" +port+url,String.class)`

Comment: Thank you , saved me a lot of effort, if anyone is interested , here is the spring doc about it:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate-uri

"That means if the input URL String is already encoded, it will be encoded twice"